# GWT Java привязка кнопок

Tags: java, gwt

Ребят, такой вопрос, есть страница настроек, стоит CheckBox и нужно, что бы при включенном флаге отображалась на странице таблица (это сейчас так и есть), но при снятом флаге нужно что бы данная таблица исчезала/замораживалась. Как это можно по логике реализовать?

Answer (score 1):

Это можно сделать в javascipt-е, не использую GWT или Java

чекбокс в html

`<input type="checkbox" name="c1" onclick="showMe('div1')">Show Hide Checkbox`

функция js, которая скрывает/показывает таблицу

```
function showMe (box) {

    var chboxs = document.getElementsByName("c1");
    var vis = "none";
    for(var i=0;i<chboxs.length;i++) { 
        if(chboxs[i].checked){
         vis = "block";
            break;
        }
    }
    document.getElementById(box).style.display = vis;


}
```

Comment: спасибо за ответ, но стэк технолгий не позволяет использовать js, но думаю благодаря вашему ответу напишу под себя. Спасибо

Comment: ну gwt генерирует javascipt на стороне java, так что в использовании javascipt-а в чистом виде мне кажется нет ничего криминального

Comment: конечно, если таблица постоянно обновляется и тяжелая нужно подумать над каким-то более оптимальным решением

Comment: Я не один же работаю, проект большой и если кто затронет эту тему там ногу сломит